# Calculate the minimum amount of student to be in a class for it to be more than 50% likely that two of them end up with the same ID digits

Tags: probability, self-study, birthday-paradox

> Question:
>
> Suppose a professor assigns exam seating using the last 4 digits student's ID. How large
> could a class be before it is more likely than not that at least two students will not be able to determine their seat uniquely?

I have tried to use the birthday paradox solver but I kinda came to a dead end.
I don't necessarily want the solution itself but more of a nudge in the right direction since I don't know which formula I should be using

Comment: But how does the professor select the seat from the id's? How many seats are there?

Comment: The professor selects the seat ID's randomly with replacement. And I think the number of seats is what we are trying to solve for

Comment: Please search our site for the [Birthday problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=birthday+problem) and choose an answer that suits you.

Comment: I have tried but I havent really found anything that solves for the amount of people we need. Everything I found so far solves for literally every other variable except the amount of seats necessary to make the probability greater